# Neo4J - Cypher Query using Predicate function not fetching desired output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and Cypher and trying to pull all Cities that do not have even a single hospital offering Oncology Treatment
I've written below query using ALL() function however it is even returning those Cities that have atleast one hospital that do not offer Oncology treatment

```
MATCH Y= (p:Procedure)-[:DONE_AT]->(h:Hospital)-->(g:Cities) 
WHERE ALL(x in nodes(Y) WHERE p.Procedure_Name<>'ONCOLOGY')
RETURN g, h
```

I know when we look at the pattern in path Y it might be returning correct output however need help on my requirement

Thanks for looking into it..

Answer (score 2):

Your current query matches paths consisting of a single :Procedure, a single :Hospital, and a single :Cities node per path, which explains why you're getting the results you're seeing. The `WHERE all()` approach won't work for this, because you're running it per path, so it's checking that `p`, `h`, and `g` don't have an oncology procedure, and I'm pretty sure you meant it to only apply to all procedures per hospital.

A better way to go about this is to match to hospitals that don't have an Oncology procedure like this:

```
MATCH (h:Hospital)
WHERE NOT (:Procedure{Procedure_Name:'ONCOLOGY'})-[:DONE_AT]->(h)
MATCH (h)-->(g:Cities) 
RETURN h, g
```

If you're only looking for cities without a hospital that has done an oncology treatment, then you could use this:

```
MATCH (g:Cities)
WHERE NOT (:Procedure{Procedure_Name:'ONCOLOGY'})-[:DONE_AT]->(:Hospital)-->(g)
RETURN g
```

Comment: Yes your second query is what I was looking for. Thanks for a quick response..really appreciate it :)